# FileOutputStream is slow. How can this be done faster?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

```
        File file = new File(directory + ".zip");
        if(file.exists()) {
            return;
        }
        url = new URL("http://someURL" +  session);
        is = url.openStream();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int data;
        //Leser forbi det første tegnet
        is.read();
        while ((data = is.read()) != -1) {
                fos.write(data);
        }
        is.close();
        fos.close();
```

My program freezes for 20 when i call this method. How can this process be done any faster?

Comment: Don't use dialup?  To avoid locking up your program, you should be doing this asynchronously.

Comment: Where exactly does it hang? If it freezes for 20 (seconds?) then it might be just from getting the connection.

Comment: Yes i thought of that too. I dont really know what to say. I've been doing some reading, and it seems like other ppl have had the same problem. It freezes exactly when this method is called. When i log in to my application, this methods executes to get the ZipFormat on the url into a zipFile. But it takes so loooong.

Answer (score 8):

Use a buffer to transfer a small trunk of data at a time instead of reading a byte a time. This will be much more resource efficient for large files. I guess your zip file is big.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int n = 0;
while (-1 != (n = is.read(buffer))) {
   fos.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

couple if things you can try:

- You can use `FileChannel` and `ByteBuffer` to improve the performance. Specially the size of the `ByteBuffer` will do the magic.

  ```
  FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(infile);        
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
  FileChannel fcin = fin.getChannel();
  fcin.read(buffer);
  ```
- If you are copying from one to another you can directly use

  `fileChannel.transferFrom(ReadableByteChannel src, long position, long count)`

Which is pretty fast as does not copy the content to user space. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29).

- You can instead use `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024)` instead of `ByteBuffer.allocate(1024)`.

The buffers returned by this method typically have some what higher allocation and deallocation costs than non-direct buffers. The contents of direct buffers may reside outside of the normal garbage-collected heap, and so their impact upon the memory footprint of an application might not be obvious. It is therefore recommended that direct buffers be allocated primarily for large, long-lived buffers that are subject to the underlying system's native I/O operations. In general it is best to allocate direct buffers only when they yield a measurable gain in program performance. [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can't make it go faster, but you can prevent it from blocking using Java NIO APIs.  This will allow the program to pass back control to the thread while it is downloading the file in the background.

Comment: Certainly he can make it go faster. A bit of buffering will work wonders.